# how do you publish rCharts with knitHTML

Tags: r, knitr, rcharts

I am trying to publish rCharts in knitrHTML, I keep getting this error:

```
Quitting from lines 11-43 (ddd.Rmd) 
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> writeLines -> file

Execution halted
```

this is my kode within the markdown:

```
rPlot(cpubusy ~ datetime, color = 'machine', type = 'point', data = server)
```

How could I resolve this? what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See - [Ramnath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168464/2-knitr-r-markdown-rstudio-issues-highcharts-and-morris-js/17176191#17176191) answer.

Basically to add `rCharts` and have it rendered within `knitr` you need to the `print` method and `include_assets = TRUE`. This will tell `knitr` to add the `JS` and `CSS` assets required for `rCharts`.

Also make sure you have `{r results = 'asis', comment = NA}` for your chunk.

````
```{r results = 'asis', comment = NA}
   p <- rPlot(speed ~ dist, data = cars, type = 'point')
   p$print('chart', include_assets = TRUE)
```
````

Comment: @amvill04, when I do p$print('chart', include_assets = TRUE)
it prints the values to the document, not the charts.

Comment: @user1471980 have you added `{r results = 'asis', comment = NA}` to your chunk? You need the `results = 'asis'` so `knitr` does not process it further.

Comment: yes, as this ```{r results, echo=FALSE, comment = NA}

Comment: see above. You have missed the `"asis"` for the `result`. It needs to read `{r results = 'asis', comment = NA}`